# Segmentation fault when dealing with matrix embedded in struct

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, struct, segmentation-fault

I'm working on an application that deals with Bayes Networks, in C. I have the following struct to represent a model, which is essentially just a transition matrix and a list of the states.

```
typedef struct {
    char **states;  /* Array of state names */
    double **transition_mat;  /* Transition matrix */
} model_t;
```

However, when I try to work with the transition matrix of a model, I get a Segmentation Fault. I am instantiating a model as follows:

```
model_t *model = malloc(sizeof(model_t));
model->transition_mat = malloc(NUM_STATES * sizeof(double *));

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
    model->transition_mat[i] = malloc(NUM_STATES * sizeof(double));
}
```

(here, `NUM_STATES` is simply the number of states that the model has). With `NUM_STATES = 8` I've initialized a model as above and then I try the following:

```
model->transition_mat[6][2] = 0.121;
```

which results in the aforementioned Segmentation Fault.

Anyone see why this is happening? I believe that I am correctly allocating memory, but that seems to be the source of my error.

Comment: Use a debugger and post result .As code you posted doesn't seem to have any problem .

Comment: If `NUM_STATES` is a `#define`, why not simplify your life and just have a `double transition_mat[NUM_STATES][NUM_STATES];` in the structure?

Comment: Check the results of your function calls when it matters to you.  The return value of `malloc()` *always* matters to you.  It is `NULL` on error, and if that slips by unnoticed then subsequently dereferencing that produces undefined behavior (likely a segfault).  That's unlikely to be your issue here unless `NUM_STATES` is very large, but you don't know.

Comment: The code works fine for me. I did try a few permutations and the only time I got segfault is when the subscripts went beyond NUM_STATES.

Answer (score 0):

What is stopping you from doing something like this (as you seem to have NUM_STATES as a #define anyways.

```
typedef struct {
char states[NUM_STATES]
double transition_mat[NUM_STATES][NUM_STATES]
} model_t;
```

Also, always check if malloc() returns NULL. Because that means memory allocation failed. If that slips by your program and you then consequently attempt to use a thing you could not allocate memory to you are basicly asking to get a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure your issue is related to the code you've posted as the following works fine with gcc 4.8 on my system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char **states;
    double **transition_mat;
} model_t;

int main()
{
    int NUM_STATES=8;
    int i;

    model_t *model = malloc(sizeof(model_t));
    model->transition_mat = malloc(NUM_STATES * sizeof(double *));

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
    model->transition_mat[i] = malloc(NUM_STATES * sizeof(double));
    }

    model->transition_mat[6][2] = 0.121;

    printf("transition_mat[6][2] = %g\n", model->transition_mat[6][2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Have you checked the return values of your calls to malloc?

You could try removing the pointer and see if you get a similar issue, that may help narrow down the issue:

```
model_t model;
model.transition_mat = malloc(NUM_STATES * sizeof(double *));

for (i = 0; i < NUM_STATES; i++) {
model.transition_mat[i] = malloc(NUM_STATES * sizeof(double));
}

model.transition_mat[6][2] = 0.121;
```